# Currency Denominations Affecting Prices

Tags: reference-request, currency, price-theory

My question regards how currency denominations might artificially affect prices. For example, a baseball game that determines a good pricing scheme for parking would be charging 7 dollars per person. But, due to the difficulty of exchanging change with everyone, may decide to instead charge 10 dollars for the convienence. I am wondering if there has been any research done in this area, and if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Specifically, I am looking at how cash denominations alter prices for convienence on the transaction.

Comment: In most cases, price is all about demand-supplies(and also monopoly). Only during special situation : When India announce to scrap 500, 1000 rupee denomination. It cause a surge on price to trader that willing to take the denomination.